# Facebook button does not work with Iron-Router

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, iron-router

I have a route

```
this.route('blabla', {
  template: 'FacebookLikeButton'

});
```

A template with the Facebook button code

```
<template name="FacebookLikeButton">
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.con/mywebsite"       data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

When I go directly to localhost:3000/blabla, the button is displayed.
But when I do Router.go('blabla'), the button does not show up. With a DOM inspector, I can see that the Facebook tags are here, the script is executed, but for some reason, the button does not show up. It does if you refresh the page.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it:

```
Template.FacebookLikeButton.rendered = function() {
 try {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
 }catch(e) {}   
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I got your desired functionality to work on this [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/AKKTmzPkSoecX5uxN/Facebook%20Button).

It basically works like this:

The home template has a button that uses `Router.go('blahblah')` to get to the next template and it does render appropriately.

So, you template looks like:

```
<template name="home">
  <button class="test">Go to fb</button>
</template>
<template name="FacebookLikeButton">
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.con/mywebsite"       data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</template>
```

Routes:

```
Router.route('/', {
  template: 'home'
});
Router.route('blahblah', {
  template: 'FacebookLikeButton'
});
```

Client-side JS:

```
Template.home.events({
  'click .test' : function(e, tpl) {
    Router.go('blahblah'); 
  }
});
```